# How to pass string value to storedp procedure that want decimal value

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, parameters, sqldatasource

i have this problem and I don't know how to solve:

-in an .aspx page a SqlDataSource calls a stored procedure
-i pass parameter in code-behind 
-i have to pass string value but the parameter is decimal in the stored procedure
-running i get the conversion error, what to do?

```
//code behind
Parameter prm_price = new Parameter("cc_price", DbType.Decimal, newValues["PRICE"].ToString());

sqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(prm_price);
```

-

```
//stored procedure
@cc_prezzo decimal(15,3),
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you just have to cast the string before sending it. If its a decimal you can cast it in a float before sending it and when you receive it back you just have to recast it in  a String.

I don't know which langages your are using but you could do something like that

```
sqlDataSource.InsertParameters.Add(Float.Parse(prm_price));
```